# Guardar variables extensas en archivos aparte

Tags: php, symfony3

Estoy trabajando con un controlador que realiza sentencias SQL **muy** extensas, por lo que mi código termina hecho un asco de 2000 líneas de puro String para pasar a `executeQuery()`, ¿Hay una buena práctica (tampoco quiero hacer uso de métodos inmantenibles o que rompan el modelo MVC) para almacenar esas consultas SQL en variables en algún archivo externo que pueda ser utilizado por el controlador? ¿Me veo obligado a seguir almacenándolas en variables locales al controlador? ¿Los services podrían servir, o no es una opción válida?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias dejar las sentencias en otro archivo y hacer el respectivo include once y pasarselo al executeQuery

Comment: Hola! Disculpame la tardanza, y gracias por responder, voy a tratar y te aviso!

Comment: Me veo con problemas en este sentido: Symfony no me permite incluir archivos externos, busqué y decían de agregar desde la configuración del composer, pero ni así porque es una muy mala práctica.

Comment: Hay muchas maneras de abarcar esto, todas pueden valer. Puedes generer un servicio que se dedique únicamente a devolverte el string de la consulta, y usando el Dependency Inyector de SF3 lo instancias y lo recuperas. En algún proyecto en el que he trabajado se empeñaron en almacenar las consultas en un XML, y usábamos una clase propia para obtener y preparar las consultas. Lo que uses dependerá mucho de ti, ya te digo, todas las opciones son válidas. Lo que sí puedo decirte  es que symfony es lo suficientemente flexible para permitirte integrar casi cualquier solución.